# how to give href value in data list view?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am using lightbox to show images in enlarge on same page. i have defined in data list view a href tag to get image link and when the user click will get enlarge thumbinal. can anyone tell me how to give href value ?
 my code is here.

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataKeyField="ImageID" 
                    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" RepeatColumns="3">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" 
                            ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ImageURL","~/Images/{0}") %>' BorderColor="#009900" 
                            BorderStyle="Groove" BorderWidth="5px" Height="300px" Width="300px" />
                         <a href='<%# Eval("ImageURL","~/Images/{0}") %>' rel="lightbox" title='<%# Eval("ImageURL","~/Images/{0}") %>'><asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataKeyField="ImageID" 
                    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" RepeatColumns="3">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" 
                            ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ImageURL","~/Images/{0}") %>' BorderColor="#009900" 
                            BorderStyle="Groove" BorderWidth="5px" Height="300px" Width="300px" />
                         <a href='<%# Eval("ImageURL","~/Images/{0}") %>' rel="lightbox" title='<%# Eval("ImageURL","~/Images/{0}") %>'><img src='<%# Eval("ImageURL","~/Images/{0}") %>' />"</a>
                        <br />
                        ImageID:
                        <asp:Label ID="ImageIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ImageID") %>' />
                        <br />
                        UploadedBy:
                        <asp:Label ID="UploadedByLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("UploadedBy") %>' />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:DataList></a>
                        <br />
                        ImageID:
                        <asp:Label ID="ImageIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ImageID") %>' />
                        <br />
                        UploadedBy:
                        <asp:Label ID="UploadedByLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("UploadedBy") %>' />
                        <br />
                        <br />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:DataList>
```

Advance thanks!

Comment: Your code contains duplicate code. You also should set the link around the image, instead of an empty a-tag

Comment: just for testing purpose used a-tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for a path starting with "~" to resolve I'm pretty sure you have add runat="server" to the control so that it's processed by .NET as a .NET control. Otherwise the HREF path will just have  "~/images/{0}"  which is meaningless in html .. so

```
 <a href='<%# Eval("ImageURL","~/Images/{0}") %>' rel="lightbox" title='<%# Eval("ImageURL","~/Images/{0}") %>'>
```

becomes

```
 <a href='<%# Eval("ImageURL","~/Images/{0}") %>' rel="lightbox" title='<%# Eval("ImageURL","~/Images/{0}") %>' runat="server">
```

which should make your href path resolve properly

same with the image

```
 <img src='<%# Eval("ImageURL","~/Images/{0}") %>' runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a asp:hyperlink it has an ImageURL and a NavigateUrl.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink.aspx

```
<asp:HyperLink id="hyperlink1" 
              ImageUrl="images/pict.jpg"
              NavigateUrl="http://www.microsoft.com"
              Text="Microsoft Official Site"
              Target="_new"
              runat="server"/>
```